# Combining catkin with premake4

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have a library which uses premake4 for generating the makefiles. Is there a way to combine this in catkin, without writing the CMake files for the library? Worst case I can make the CMake files myself but I'd rather keep the library as-is.

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154116/combining-catkin-with-premake4/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on how you want to package the library it might be an option to just call the library build as a custom build step from catkin.
This will make it easier to integrate updates from upstream. Depending on the interface it might be harder to integrate it with ROS, especially when the builds aren't ABI compatible.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-04-17**:
Hmm yes that would work I suppose. So I add the generating of makefiles using premake4 and the building of the library as a custom build step, then just link to it like any other library. Thanks!